# How many Redshift nodes (dc1.large) do I need to store 0.2 TB?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

A dc1.large node on Amazon Redshift can store 0.16 TB on a SSD. 
If I do have 0.2 TB of data:

- Do I have to switch to e. g. ds2.xlarge with the capacity of 2 TB?
- Can I add two dc1.large nodes to the cluster so I have the capacity of 2 * 0.16 TB = 0.32 TB?

Long question short: Do multiple nodes on Redshift add up or just mirror each other? Are multiple nodes performance increasing or space increasing?

inb4: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minimum cluster size is 2 nodes. Redundancy is factored in so you get the full storage. It's easy to add nodes so no reason to get dc1.8xlarge unless you know you need the storage...and have lots of money ;-)

Comment: Oops...minimum of 2 only applies to the 8xlarge sizes. Here's more info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html

Comment: it east to add nodes but sometimes the problem is with the storage and then you need to add nodes since the dc1.large nodes contain 160GB

Answer (score 0):

You can use up to 32 "small" nodes (`dc1.large`, `ds2.large`) in a Redshift cluster before you have to switch to the larger node types. Storage is additive.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple nodes increase both space and performance. Your data gets distributed between nodes according to the [rules you set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html) and processed by each node independently. More about the node types (dc vs ds) in a nice guide [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/setting-up-redshift-cluster.html)